How to personalize the style of a comment?
I want to create a comment which is removable. Therefore I'm using the comment package, but I want to change the style of the comment to make it more visible, like this :

And, this is my code (I precise that all required packages are loaded) :
\documentclass{report}

\excludecomment{prof}
\renewenvironment{prof}{
\sffamily \small
\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcetoile, barre=snake, noborder]{\normalfont\textsl{Professor's notes}}
}{
\end{bclogo}
}

% \excludecomment{prof}
% \includecomment{prof}

\begin{document}
Always visible text

\begin{prof}
Removable text, if wanted
\end{prof}

Always visible text
\end{document}

I want that these lines :
\excludecomment{prof}
\renewenvironment{prof}{
\sffamily \small
\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcetoile, barre=snake, noborder]{\normalfont\textsl{Professor's notes}}
}{
\end{bclogo}
}

goes in my own package, and after that, I can in each document add or not the professor's notes.
But, if you uncomment the \excludecomment{prof} or \includecomment{prof}, an error appears because there is too many \endgroup (because you have too many \excludecomment and/or \includecomment).
Has anybody an idea to fix that ?

NB : How I thought it was going to work : The \excludecomment{prof} creates the prof comment. And the \renewcommand{prof}{}{} would change the style.

More visible but removable? Consider use todonotes  (e.g. here).

I tried to test some things, but I failed to personalize it to what I want.
First, will you use \newcommand ou \newenvironment ?
I want more to use and environment, but \todo seems very diffilcult to use to define a new environment.

Why do you need a new environment? A new command could have sense  if you want always set the same  long options to simplify \todo[your-long-options]{comment} to \foo{comment} but  some options (e.g. background color)  can be set also as package options (e.g, \usepackage[color=cyan!20}{todonotes}) and then you only need  to use the standard \todo{comment} to make cyan notes without  any macro. Unfortunately, some options as inline are only available at the command level, so in this cases a custom macro could be useful.
